# how to waitOn data ready using iron-router and publish-composite

Tags: meteor, undefined, iron-router, meteor-publications

I have the following route :

```
this.route('groupPage', {
path: '/group/:_groupId',
waitOn: function(){
return Meteor.subscribe("groupPage", this.params._groupId);
},
data: function() {
var group = Groups.findOne({_id: this.params._groupId});

var members = Meteor.users.find({_id : {$in: group.memberIds}}); ******** ISSUE HERE******

return {
group: group,
members: members,

}; }});
```

and the following publication :

```
Meteor.publishComposite('groupPage', function(groupId, sortOrder,    limit) {
return {
// return the group
find: function() {

    if(this.userId){
      var selector = {_id: groupId};
      var options = {limit: 1};

      return  Groups.find(selector, options);
    }
    else{
      return ;
    }
 },


children: [


    {  // return the members
      find: function(group) {

          var selector = {_id: {$in: group.memberIds} };
          return Meteor.users.find(selector);
      }
    }
 ]}}) ;
```

Now my issue is that : when the related page renders for the first there is no problems but when i actualize the group Page view the line : var members = Meteor.users.find({_id : {$in: group.memberIds}}); gives me the error : undefined object don't have memberIds property. i guess it's because the subscription is not yet ready when doing group.memberIds , isn't it ? Please a hint.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The data function doesn't wait for the subscription to be ready. Further more, subscriptions in the router are considered an anti-pattern for the most part, and should be done in the template: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

I would pass to the template the groupId, and then get the group and members in the template, like so:

```
this.route('groupPage', {
  path: '/group/:_groupId',

  data: function() {
    return {
      _groupId: this.params._groupId,
    }
  }
});
```

and then in the template file:

```
Template.groupPage.onCreated(function(){
  this.subscribe("groupPage", this.data._groupId);
})

Template.groupPage.helpers({
  members(function(){
   tempInst = Template.instance()
   var group = Groups.findOne({_id: tempInst.data._groupId});
   return Meteor.users.find({_id : {$in: group.memberIds}});

  })
})
```

Comment: You're right if router == flowRouter, wrong if router = i-r

Comment: @MichelFloyd nope, still an anti-pattern with iron-router

Comment: He's using `waitOn`. That along with `subscribe` and `data` are all [documented](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-specific-options) and quite commonly used in i-r.

Answer (score 0):

The general pattern of your route and publication are all solid. I suspect it's something simple such as:

- There is no group with the `_id` you're using
- You're not logged in when you load the route

Here's a version of your code that guards against the error. Note that the publication executes `this.ready()` instead of just returning if the user is not logged in.

```
this.route('groupPage', {
  path: '/group/:_groupId',
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe("groupPage", this.params._groupId);
  },
  data: function() {
    var group = Groups.findOne({_id: this.params._groupId});
    var members = group && Meteor.users.find({_id : {$in: group.memberIds}});     
    return { group: group, members: members };
  }
});

Meteor.publishComposite('groupPage', function(groupId,sortOrder,limit) {
  return {
    find: function() {
      if (this.userId) return Groups.find(groupId);
      this.ready()
    }
  },

  children: [
    find: function(group) {
      var selector = {_id: {$in: group.memberIds} };
      return Meteor.users.find(selector);
    }
  ]
});
```